# How can I replace x in a polynomial by some other polynomial in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How can I replace `x` in a polynomial by some other polynomial in Python? For example, I had `p = poly1d([1,1,1])`, which is `x^2+x+1`, now I want to replace `x` by `y^2` and get `y^4+y^2+1`. It's like the composition of two functions.

Comment: Please show the code you are using. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't understand why this question was closed as "why isn't this code working". There is no code. The answers show that this question can be easily answered without seeing any code at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [numpy.polyval](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html) to compose polynomials using NumPy. For example:

```
import numpy as np

p1 = np.poly1d([1, 1, 1])
print (p1)
p2 = np.poly1d([1, 0, 0], variable = 'y')
print (p2)
p = np.polyval(p1, p2)
p = np.poly1d(p, variable = 'y')
print (p)
```

will print:

```
   2
1 x + 1 x + 1
   2
1 y
   4     2
1 y + 1 y + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can substitute polynomials into other polynomials in NumPy:

```
In [2]: p = np.poly1d([1,1,1])    # x^2 + x + 1
In [3]: y2 = np.poly1d([1,0,0])   # x^2
In [4]: p(y2)
Out[4]: poly1d([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.])   # x^4 + x^2 + 1
```